# Payment preference, Mercadopago's SDK & Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, mercadopago

I'm having a problem while integrating MercadoPago's SDK and Laravel 5.5

**Error message:**

MercadoPagoException (400)
Wrong number of parameters

**Screen:**

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t67TJ.png)

**Payment Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\Cart;
use Exception;
use MP;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * Display a listing of the resource.
   *
   * @return Response
   */
  public function process(Request $request)
  {

    $mp = new MP (env('MP_CLIENT_ID'), env('MP_CLIENT_SECRET'));

    $user = auth()->user();
    $prefix = 'VSHOPREF-';
    $external_reference = $prefix . $request->ctoken;
    $token = $request->ctoken;

    $preferenceData = [
        'external_reference' => $external_reference,
        'payer'              => [
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email
        ],
        'back_urls' => [
        'success' => env('APP_URL').'/gracias',
        'pending' => env('APP_URL').'/gracias',
        'failure' => env('APP_URL').'/error'
        ],
        'notification_url' => env('MP_NOTIFICATION_URL'),
        'auto_return' => 'all'
    ];

    $entries = Cart::where('session_id', '=', $token)->get();
    foreach ($entries as $e):
        $preferenceData['items'][] = [
            'title'       => $e->product_name,
            'category_id' => 'zapato',
            'quantity'    => $e->qty,
            'currency_id' => 'VEF',
            'unit_price'  => $e->price,
        ];
    endforeach;

    //dd($preferenceData);
    $preference = $mp->create_preference($preferenceData);
    dd($preference);

    //return init point to be redirected
    //return $preference['response']['init_point'];

  }
}
```

**Form I'm using to send the payment information**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{!! route('payment.process') !!}" method="post">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input type="hidden" name="ctoken" id="ctoken" value="{!! $cart_token !!}">
                <input type="submit" name="pagar" value="Pagar" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-sm">
              </form>
```

Btw, I'm sorry for my bad english. I hope you can help me with this issue.

**EDIT 1**

Thanks to [Alexey Mezenin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227923/alexey-mezenin)

Well, i wrote "MP_CIENT_SECRET" instead of "MP_CLIENT_SECRET" on my .env file.

**NEW ERROR**

MercadoPagoException (400)
currency_id invalid

Comment: What package exactly do you use? And what `dd(env('MP_CLIENT_ID'), env('MP_CLIENT_SECRET'));` show if you put these in the very beginning of the `process` method?

Comment: Well, i wrote "MP_CIENT_SECRET" instead of "MP_CLIENT_SECRET" on my .env file. Now it shows me a new error:

MercadoPagoException (400)
currency_id invalid